# Handling Chinese /Japense characters in sqoop import

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, db2, sqoop

I am trying to do sqoop import from db2, where table contains Chinese characters in 2 columns like 燃油油位传感器

Using below sqoop command:

```
sqoop job -conf /app1/sqoop-metastore/jdcp/sqoop-site.xml --create <jobname> 
-- import --connect <connectionstring> --username <xxx> --password-file <xxx> 
--table <ttt> --target-dir <targetpath> --fields-terminated-by '\007' --map- 
column-java DTC_NAME=String,DTC_DESC=String -m 1 --delete-target-dir
```

Getting below error:

> Error: java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue
>       Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][1065][12306][4.15.120] Caught java.io.CharConversionException.  See attached Throwable for details. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null
>       **Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1**
>       at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.q.a(q.java:45)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jc.a(jc.java:2862)
>       ... 20 more

Could you please provide some pointers?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your target-Db2-database (or table/column/tablespace ) encoding and territory?  What's your sqoop session locale ? What Db2-driver *version* are you using?

Comment: Can you try Sqoop HIve import  with `--query` option use `--map-column-hive` with Sqoop hive import

Comment: Did you try https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/99600/sqoop-import-special-characters.html or https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/198290/native-sqoop-export-from-hdfs-fails-for-unicode-ch.html?